# Using A Struct Object in a Function

Tags: c++, function, windows-7, struct

I have written a piece of code for queue.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct q
        {
            int items[10];
            int front,rear;
        } queue;

void Addqueue(struct q *queue, int item)
{
    if (queue->rear==9)
        cout << "Queue is Full.";
    else
        queue->items[++queue->rear]=item;
}


int main()
{
    queue.front=queue.rear=-1;
    Addqueue(q *queue,5);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I have used struct object for it. In Addqueue Function, first element is (struct q *queue), I want to know what should I write instead of it, while I'm caling this function in main function, for example I tested Addqueue(q *queue,5) and Addqueue(queue,5) and Addqueue(*queue,5) and Addqueue(struct q *queue,5), but none of them works and I will get an error for this line. so what should I do? what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct q
{
    int items[10];
    int front,rear;
} queue;

void Addqueue(q *queue, int item)
{
    if (queue->rear==9)
        cout << "Queue is Full.";
    else
        queue->items[++queue->rear]=item;
}


int main()
{
    queue.front=queue.rear=-1;
    Addqueue(&queue, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

That's correct way.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is `Addqueue(&queue, 5)`. `Addqueue` accepts a pointer to a `struct q`, so you need to get `queue`'s address with the address-of `operator&` to pass in.

That said, you should absolutely use [`std::queue<int>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/) instead of your own home-grown queue.

Answer (score 1):

You created pointer to struct `q`, but it has not allocated memory. And local name of pointer `q *queue` override your object `queue`.